# Quartz hijacks Log4j.properties-file

Tags: java, log4j, quartz-scheduler

I have a project that uses log4j, it had a log4.properties-file that worked perfectly fine.

I then introduced Quartz 2.1.6, now it seems to have overridden the file that was previously used. Log4j comes with Quartz and Quartz has a properties-file but I can't figure out what to change in order to make it use the old one.

Is there a way to make Quartz print what log4j.properties is being used?

I have tried `-Dlog4j.configuration` in my runtime but no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you determine that quartz overrid your log4.properties-file? You do know that Quartz uses slf4j internally, and if you want quartz logs to print using your log4j config you need to add the slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path?

Comment: I have all the required .jars-on the class path, I don't even know what file/output it logs writes to now. The "old" file that it use to log to doesn't get any action.

Comment: I removed the quartz temporariliy, that made it "work" since it now uses the log4j.properties that I want to use, but as soon as I add quartz it doesn't use my log4j.properties-file.